# Ngx-chips populate <tag-input> doesn't post the <tag-input> HTML object onFocus of input

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

This code is used to populate auto suggest field with

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields; let i=index">
    <label class="pt-3 font-600">{{field.label}} {{field.id}}</label>
    <tag-input
      [identifyBy]="'id'"
      [inputClass]="riProSuggestionField"
      [displayBy]="'name'"
      (onFocus)="onFocusInput($event)"
      [placeholder]="field.placeholder"
      [(ngModel)]="field.data"
      [inputId]="field.id"
      [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true"
      name="{{field.label}}"
    >
      <tag-input-dropdown
      [autocompleteObservable]="getSuggestions"
      </tag-input-dropdown>
    </tag-input>
  </div>
```

On `.ts` file

```
onFocusInput(event) {
}
```

In this function it should give the html object of `<tag-input>` , Does anybody have trick to get this HTML object `onFocusInput` ?

Comment: can you please tell me what data do you want to get from that event?